# Origin of "someone is a character"

Tags: etymology

The [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/character) has

> If you say that someone is a character, you mean that they are
>   interesting, unusual, or amusing.

I haven't been able to find an origin of this usage. Where does it come from?

Comment: Talking about someone’s character and saying someone “is a character” are two very different things, in different registers.

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford English Dictionary (*[character](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/30639)*, n.) reports this definition along with several examples. The two earliest ones suggest the usage came about in the late 18th and early 19th centuries.

> 15. c. *colloquial*. An odd, extraordinary, or eccentric person.
>
> 1773   O. Goldsmith *She stoops to Conquer* ii. 24   A very impudent fellow this! **but he's a character**, and I'll humour him.
>
> 1832   G. Downes *Lett. from* *Continental Countries* I. 473   ‘Ahi lassa’, added with a sigh the old man, **who was a bit of a character**.

The distinguishing feature is that the person is extraordinary, or that they stand out due to some oddity, eccentricity, or (to go by your definition) entertainment value.

This usage likely comes from the more generic sense of someone's *character* as personality and moral quality. Again from the OED:

> 9.a.The sum of the moral and mental qualities which distinguish an individual or a people, viewed as a homogeneous whole; a person's or group's individuality deriving from environment, culture, experience, etc.; mental or moral constitution, personality.
>
> 1666   H. Bennet Let. 9 Feb. in Lett. Earl of Arlington to Sir William Temple (1701) 60   Tho he had Opiniastred the Point, **as restily as became his Character**, yet we are perswaded that..he is not dissatisfied.
>
> 1726   Bp. J. Butler 15 Serm. xii. 234   There is greater Variety of Parts **in what we call a Character**, than there are Features in a Face.

These and similar personal meanings for *character* (including the name of a person portrayed on stage by an actor) became popular in the 17th century. They are all figurative uses originating from the sense of *character* as mark, letter (today seen in uses like the *number of characters* in a text field), or imprint. The first documented figurative use referred to the imprint left by baptism upon one's soul:

> 1. a. In figurative contexts (cf. branch II.). In earliest use spec. the indelible quality which baptism, confirmation, and holy orders imprint on the soul (see indelible adj. c).
>
> 1502   tr. *Ordynarye of Crysten Men* (de Worde) i. iii. sig. d.iii   A **spirytuel token** yt these theologiens calle **caractere** [Fr. caractere], the whiche maye neuer be defaced.

To sum up, *character* began as a kind of mark or imprint, then was used to describe how a soul or spirit was marked, then was generalized to personality or moral quality in general, and thence applied to people and especially to remarkable or extraordinary people.

Answer (score -1):

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Character), on '**Character'** gives a shorter version of TaliesinMerlin's answer::

> Meaning "a person" in the abstract is from 1749; especially "eccentric person" (1773). Colloquial sense of "chap, fellow" is from 1931.

But earlier than this is **character actor.**

> Character-actor, one who specializes in characters with marked peculiarities, is attested from 1861.